# Can we query GZIP compressed files?

Tags: gzip, apache-pig, hdfs

I have a huge GZIP file in HDFS.

I want to know if we can query this GZIP file using Pig.

If so, What command can we use?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

For example PigStorage has support for GZIP files. If the file has suffix .gz, PigStorage will automatically extract the data while loading it.